# How to call a private class from a public class

Tags: java, android

I have the following `private class`:

```
private class sendReportePeriodico extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        socket = null;
        SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(server_address, server_port);
        socket = new Socket();
        try {
            socket.connect(address, 3000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            socket.setSoTimeout(3000);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Can't Connect";
        }
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);

        output.print(texto);
        output.flush();

        return null;
    }
}
```

I need to `call` this class `inside` this a `public class`:

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d("LogXXX","Visualizando gps");
    texto = "GPS: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude();
    tvMensaje.setText(texto);
    mapa(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    new sendReportePeriodico();

    HERE I NEED TO CALL THE PRIVATE CLASS;
 }
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Is the private class and the method inside the same class?  If not, then you can't do it.

Comment: Is top level `private` class allowed in Java?

Answer (score 0):

It does not really matter that the class you´re calling from is public.
If the class "sendReportePeriodico" is not in another class then there is no way to call it.

Private classes are useless unless they´re located inside another class (In this case it is referred to as "inner class").

Even reflection would not work since private classes take an instance of the outter class as an argument using reflection)

The solution would be to make the class "sendReportePeriodico" public or protected or move the class inside the class you want to call it from.